# AWS: update data in redshift using lambda, python and boto3

Tags: python, lambda, amazon-redshift, boto3

first, I am very new to python and aws.
I have to encrypt one column in redshift. I decided to use lambda to do this update, but nothing worked and there was no error message.
I wonder how can I update data in redshift using lambda and how can I figure out that data has been encrypted successfully.

```
import boto3
import psycopg2
import hashlib

client = boto3.client('redshift')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname', host='host',
                       port='port', user='user', password='pwd')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM table;""")
    result = cur.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        code = hashlib.md5(row.get('code'))
    cur.execute("""UPDATE table SET code = %s;""" % code)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: You are aware you are updating the entire table with just one hash value?

Comment: @AdamOwczarczyk I know it sounds very strange but yes, I am aware of it, I have to this because of security for data.

Comment: Have you checked if the function doesn't time out? If the update is long, it may time out before finishing.

Comment: @AdamOwczarczyk yes it is, so I decided to make another table and do md5 before insert data into table